# Angularjs - show loading while getting the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I a have the following directive:

```
angular
.module('app.widgets')
.directive('myCalendarRange', myCalendarRange);

function myCalendarRange () {
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      templateUrl: '/template/is/located/here.html',
      restrict: 'EA'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    /* */
    }
}
```

How can I show a loading gif while Angular gets the template?

**UPDATE:**
I'd also like a solution which I can use for views. For example, when user goes to products page, I'd like to show the loading while angular gets the products.html

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/Products', {
          templateUrl: 'products.html',
          controller: 'productsController',

    });
```

Comment: <my-callendar-range><img src="loading.gif"></my-callendar-range>
and add "replace: true," in var directive. That should help.

Comment: @MichałIgnaszewski thanks for the answer, I'd also like a solution which I can use for views. For example, when user goes to products page, I'd like to show the loading while angular gets the products.html

Answer (score 0):

I have just do it in this way...

In the directive put an HTML with:

1. Loading code (and hide it when the template is loaded)
2. Template include (with an onload event, it is supported by angular)
3. Put a watch variable for loading in your scope

   ```
   angular
   .module('app.widgets')
   .directive('myCalendarRange', myCalendarRange);

   function myCalendarRange () {
       var directive = {
         link: link,
         /* 1 and 2 */
         template: '<span ng-hide="loading == false">Loading... GIF</span><div ng-include="<url_template>" onload="loading = false"></div>',
         restrict: 'EA'
       };
       return directive;

       function link(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.loading = true; //3
       }
   }
   ```

Using this idea you can have a Template with a loading gif while your are loading the real template (I have use this for show loading while the server generates a PayPal Form)

For your example:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/Products', {
      templateUrl: 'loading.html', //General loading with Gif and include
      controller: 'productsController',

});
```

loading.html

```
<div ng-hide="loading == false">
Loading please wait...<img src="ajax_loader_blue_64.gif" />
</div>
<div ng-include="url_template" onload="loading = false"></div>
```

productsController

```
//...
scope.url_template = 'URL to template to load set in the controller'
scope.loading = true
//...
```

Comment: Did you test the code? Documentation says that compile and link functions are paused until template is resolved. Beside, templateUrl should contain URL or id, not template itself.

Comment: I have only test the second example. I have change the templateUrl variable for template. It is just a mockup it is not working code but I thing that the idea will work.

Comment: @JDL I need to show the loading before the view's template is loaded. Where you suggest to add the  <div ng-hide="loading = false">
Loading please wait...<img src="ajax_loader_blue_64.gif" />
</div>?

Comment: @Hov You can have a loadingProduct.html with loading gif and the include. It will load inmediately as it do nothing. after a while it will load the real product.html. If you work a little you can have a loading.html which will load a template, you can set the template to load in the controller.

Comment: @JDL sorry for the slow response. loadingProduct.html is a good idea. But I'd prefer to show the .gif when angular does http GET call to get the template and hide it when the template is returned. Maybe there is a nice javascript solution... what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

use pace.js. Its easy and amazing.